# Can ChaCha20 provide integrity?

Tags: stream-cipher, modes-of-operation, integrity, chacha

I have read that in general stream ciphers do not provide data integrity. Can ChaCha20 be implemented in such a way (perhaps like counter mode with message authentication in AES) to provide this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ChaCha20 has Ind-CPA security and beyond this ( Ind-CCAx.. [[1]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26689/18298)), you need integrity and authentication. And note that Authenticated Encryption > Ind-CCA.

ChaCha20 is already teamed with [Poly1305](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305) authenticator to provide **confidentiality**, **integrity** and **authentication**. It exists in TLS standards and one of the five cipher suites in TLS 1.3 as `ChaCha20_Poly1305`.

If you are going to use ChaCha20 it is better to use XChaCha20-Poly1305 since it has larger nonce sizes (192-bit) so that randomly generated nonces are safe against the collisions, you need $2^{96}$ random nonces to hit another one with 50% probability and that is almost impossible.

Comment: *"You need $2^{96}$ random nonces to hit another one with 50% probability and that is almost impossible."*

I would just like to note that your most significant weakness was and still is a badly seeded RNG causing a collision in the nonce, e.g. at OS startup for some devices.

Comment: @orlp well, that is a general issue. One has to know about their system before going to use it for security, like this [What issues are there while using Linux's /dev/urandom for generating cryptographic keys?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/85533/18298)